# Map ArrayList with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I just coded my first Hibernate examples.

The database connection works and I understand how I can map a String from a POJO to a database field:

```
private String firstName;
```

And in the mapping file:

```
<property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="FIRSTNAME" />
</property>
```

But how can I map an ArrayList to the database? A simpl example from the mapping xml file would be appreciated.

Cheers

UPDATE

I switched to List instead of ArrayList found an example. Now I map as follows:

```
    <list name="test" inverse="false" table="CONTACT" lazy="true">
        <key>
            <column name="ID" />
        </key>
        <list-index></list-index>
        <element type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TEST" />
        </element>
    </list>
```

Unfortunately, I get an exception that I do not understand:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK6382B0003257FF7F:CONTACT [ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (CONTACT [ID,idx])
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice that you are using XML to map your POJOs. You will find some information about that [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html).

for example:

```
   <list name="myArrayListProperty" cascade="all">
        <key column="parent_id"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="WhatIsInTheList"/>
    </list>
```

However, using annotations have some advantages. [This link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection) will explain how to map any collection using annotations.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about annotations but it seems to be easier.

Answer (score 1):

See the [collection mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/collections.html) section of the docs. There are multiple ways to map a list (one-to-many, many-to-many, a collection of elements). You can map it as a list or as a bag, so read the whole section.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this kind of answer is not very helpful for somebody who is new to a certain technology. Everything is in the docs, but usually you don't understand it. I don't know how you star tlearning something new, but I put together small 'Hello World' examples. An actual code fragment would have been much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a little error in the XML configuration:

When you have a list the solution to map this list using a database is to link with a additional table, so instead of doing:

```
<list name="test" inverse="false" table="CONTACT" lazy="true">
        <key>
            <column name="ID" />
        </key>
        <list-index></list-index>
        <element type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TEST" />
        </element>
</list>
```

You should have to do map to a new data table that holds the list values:

```
<list name="test" inverse="false" table="CONTACT_test" lazy="true">
        <key>
            <column name="ID" />
        </key>
        <list-index></list-index>
        <element type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TEST" />
        </element>
</list>
```

Hibernate automatically creates the new table for you.